# Docker error on Windows 2016 "Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers"

Tags: windows, docker

I get the following error when I try to do "docker run" on my Windows 2016.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker run microsoft/sample-dotnet
Unable to find image 'microsoft/sample-dotnet:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server) to get started.

This is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872082/docker-login-error-with-get-started-tutorial) because this is Windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker login error with Get Started tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872082/docker-login-error-with-get-started-tutorial). The name is a little misleading, but looks like the same error you're having (though with a different image).

Comment: That walkthrough was recently updated to add [install Windows updates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#2-install-windows-updates) - have you done that step? If so try `docker pull microsoft/nanoserver` to see if the base image will download.

Comment: Nope the issue was the proxy.  I didn't realize that docker uses a different proxy than the Windows one you configure in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I solve this by http://stackoverflow.com/a/43016045/6521116

Answer (score 7):

same Problem for Windows. Some people wrote to delete dns 8.8.8.8 from resolve.conf
But i added this dns to my Settings (right click on docker icon -> Network -> Set DNS to Fixed (8.8.8.8)

Comment: Thanks! I have no proxy atm and this sill works! Path to settings is however:
Docker icon -> *settings* -> Network -> DNS Server - fixed 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 3):

Go to Docker settings > network > DNS server . change from automatic to fixed ( default is 8.8.8.8 ) . worked on win 10

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I needed to set the proxy as per [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/docker/configure_docker_daemon?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Here is an example of what I had to do (replacing my proxy address):

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "http://myproxy:80/", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", "https://myproxy:80/", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
restart-service docker
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly launch the docker setting and set your dns to 8.8.8.8

Comment: Still get this error: "Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password" Correlation given?

Answer (score 0):

So I faced the same problem and it took me days to figure out what to do.
Summary:

1. I disabled Hyper-V (from the Hyper-V Manager, that comes with docker-desktop)
2. I disabled every Network Adapter that is a part of Hyper-V (*vEthernet(DockerNAT), vEthernet(Default Switch)* and *Virtual-Box-Host-Only Network*)
3. In the Docker Settings, I set the *DNS* to `8.8.8.8`
4. In the Docker Settings, I set *Proxy* to `no-Proxy`
5. In the *General* Docker Settings, I checked `"Expose Daemon on tcp[..]"`
6. I reactivated the following network adapters: *vEthernet(DockerNAT), vEthernet(Default Switch)* and *Virtual-Box-Host-Only Network*
7. I restarted (enabled) Hyper-V
8. I restarted Docker
9. In my console I tried `docker run hello-world`
10. Pull works! Login works! Everything works! -> Time to get a coffee

Answer (score -1):

**Ubuntu, Centos**

```
Create a file called /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf that 
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
adds the HTTP_PROXY environment variable:

[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://172.28.5.202:3128/"
```

**Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server, create a file called**

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf that adds the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable:
[Service]
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://172.28.5.202:3128/"
```

Flush changes:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
Restart Docker:
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

It worked!