# Docker error on Windows 7 “Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers”

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

My Problem is similar to the other two Questions:[starting tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872082/docker-login-error-with-get-started-tutorial) and [Timeout on windows 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252024/docker-error-on-windows-2016-client-timeout-exceeded-while-awaiting-headers). But none of it resolved my problem. (on my other search I didn't find any articles that could help my case > [search timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=docker%20client.timeout))

For any of the following commands:

- docker run hello-world
- docker pull hello-world
- docker login -u user -p pass

I get the same error: [image: output pull]

My proxies are correctly set to my cntlm service:
[image: proxies]

when I try to get the address with curl I get the following answer:
[image: curl get]

My docker version:
[image: docker version]

Docker info:
[image: docker info]

I've tried all the [troubleshoot](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/faqs/troubleshoot/) from this link (create a new default docker machine and so on)

Do you have any idea what could I do to download hello-world (or other) container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it:
First of all the client should be the same Version as the Server (now both are 1.13.1)

Second because I am using a Cntlm I have to create a Tunnel to forward my port from the Cntlm configuration.

```
ssh -R tunnelPort:proxy-Cntlm docker@ip.docker.machine
```

where:

*tunnelPort* will be used on the docker-machine (ex: 3000 for 127.0.0.1:**3000**)

*proxy-Cntlm* is the ip + port from cntlm.ini (ex: 127.0.0.1:3128)

*ip.docker.machine* it can be found simply by running `docker-machine ls`

One more thing! you have to adjust the **~/.ssh/config** (at least for cygwin)

```
Host docker 192.168.99.100
    Hostname 192.168.99.100
    IdentityFile "path/to/id_rsa" 
#on windows it is C:/Users/user/.docker/machine/machines/default/id_rsa when you have a default Machine
```